# OpenGl GLSL uniform set returns error

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I have a problem while getting an uniform from a shader. The line:

```
int u = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(program, uniform);
```

is used to check if the uniform defined by the string uniform is in the shader.

Here is an example check code:

```
System.out.println(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(1, "transformationMatrix")==0);
System.out.println(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(1, "projectionMatrix")==0);
```

And the result:

```
false
true
```

Here it comes the weird thing: The vertex shader code is the following:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 tex;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 nor;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 col;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

out vec3 normal;

void main(){

    normal = nor;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(pos, 1);
}
```

I have tested renaming the uniform, removing the other one, but the only one uniform OpenGL seems to recognize is the "projectionMatrix" one.

Enviroment:
Java with lwjgl
OpenGl in linux with mesa 10.4.0 (Doesn't work on Windows either)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GLSL compiler is allowed to strip unused variables from the emitted executable shader, as an optimization (fewer registers used etc.).
If the `transformationMatrix` uniform is used to compute the return value of the shader, it will then be kept in the shader, and the error will disappear.

This is not a "hard" error, feel free to ignore it. You may encounter it especially when you change the GLSL code for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 3):

`glGetUniformLocation()` returns -1 if the uniform was not found. From the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml):

> This function returns -1 if name does not correspond to an active uniform variable in program or if name starts with the reserved prefix "gl_".

So the error test needs to be:

```
System.out.println(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(1, "transformationMatrix") == -1);
System.out.println(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(1, "projectionMatrix") == -1);
```

As suggested in another answer, it is true that unused uniforms can be eliminated when the shader is compiled/linked. But this is not what you're observing in this case. 0 is a valid uniform location.